# How do I get to display 2 words, first word at the beginning and the other at the end of the same line using css?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and html.
I want to display something like this

Introduction                         ...Page.1

Chapter 1                ...Page.2

Page number is displayed at the end of the line

here's the code I wrote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p { 
    word-spacing: 5px;

}
pp { 

    text-align:end;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>

This is some text testing. 
<span class="pp">This is some text</span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float: right` for this:

```css
p { 
    word-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
p span { 
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
This is some text testing. 
<span class="pp">This is some text</span>
</p>
```

Or you can use `flexbox`

```css
p { 
    word-spacing: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p>
This is some text testing. 
<span class="pp">This is some text</span>
</p>
```